# How can I run a Bigtable HBase shell from any directory?

Tags: shell, hbase, bigtable

I started by following [these](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/installing-hbase-shell) instructions to install a hbase and configure it to hit my `BigTable` instance. That all works fine, however next up I wanted to additionally configure this installation so I can run `hbase shell` from anywhere.

So I added the following to my `.zshrc`:

```
export HBASE_HOME=/path/to/my/hbase
export PATH=$HBASE_HOME:...
```

When I run `hbase shell` now I get the following:

```
2017-04-28 09:58:45,069 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
NativeException: java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase1_2.BigtableConnection
  initialize at /Users/mmscibor/.hbase/lib/ruby/hbase/hbase.rb:42
      (root) at /Users/mmscibor/.hbase/bin/hirb.rb:131
```

I figured something was up with where it was looking for it's .jars and noticed that the `.tar` I downloaded had a lib directory so additionally tried:

```
hbase shell -cp $HBASE_HOME/lib/
```

But no luck. However, if I navigate to `$HBASE_HOME` and run `hbase shell` everything works fine again.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into the issue described here: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/issues/226

You need to set **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** in your environment, or run `gcloud auth application-default login`.